# Get reference to class that called virtual method

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to get a reference to the class that called a virtual method, from within the method defined in the abstract class?

Basically, I have an abstract class, let's say BaseAction, and this contains a virtual method, called RetrieveData:

```
public abstract class BaseAction
{
    protected virtual void RetrieveData()
    {

    }
}
```

in the implementation, I pass this virtual method into a method as an Action, something to this effect:

```
public class Action: BaseAction
{
    public Action()
    {
        ActionStatement(RetrieveData);
    }
}
```

Is is possible to get a reference to Action class, in the RetrieveData method without having to override it in the Action class, something to this effect:

```
public abstract class BaseAction
{
    protected virtual void RetrieveData()
    {
        // using reflection to get a handle on instance of Action?
    }
}
```

The reason for this is, that I want to use this virtual method in various different type of classes, each one having an ID field which needs to be modified, but I don't want to override this virtual method in each of the 20+ action classes, just to change the ID field.

I'd like this to happen in the base class, to limit the amount of code duplication.

Comment: No, but you can pass in the object instance.

Comment: Can you clear up what you mean by "class that called virtual method"? Classes don't call methods, methods are called on objects from other methods in (possibly different) objects.

Comment: Not sure about the question but using `generics` and abstract the `generic type` using `constrains` maybe can help you.

Comment: Why don't you add an ID property to your base class?

Comment: It would help if you showed some of `ActionStatement`.

Comment: The object calling a `protected` method is always available in the current method as `this`. It is the derived class.

Comment: basically, ID is in base class, however, by not overriding in specific derived class, all ID's are affected. i am building a questionnaire model, and applying specific rules per question type. all questions look exactly the same, except a change in ID. i don't want a method that must be derived in in action type, rather, do the ID change for each action in the base class, based on some event changed. if that makes sense?

Comment: IOTW `this.GetType()` will be `typeof(Action)`, ignoring the name conflict with `System.Action`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need reflection to this. You have many options:

If the ID field is common in each implemented class, just declare it in the abstract class and change the value in the `RetrieveData()` method.

```
public abstract class BaseAction
{
    protected int ID;
    protected virtual void RetrieveData()
    {

    }
}
```

If the ID field is not common across all implemented classes, you can add an abstract method and use that method to access the ID property.

```
public abstract class BaseAction
{
    protected abstract ChangeID(int value);
    protected virtual void RetrieveData()
    {
        //Do your stuff

        ChangeID(<with-new-value>);
    }
}

public class Action: BaseAction
{
    Protected override ChangeID(int value)
    {
        //Do whatever you want
    }

    public Action()
    {
        ActionStatement(RetrieveData);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just do:

```
public abstract class BaseAction
{
    protected void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType());
    }
}

public class Action : BaseAction 
{
    public void Bar() 
    {
        Foo();
    }
}

// the runtime type of foo will be Action regardless of compile-time type
BaseAction foo = new Action(); 
foo.Bar();
```

it will output `Action` - that is, in an inherited method (`Foo()`) the object `this` will already be of the inheriting type `Action` if the method was ultimately called through an object of *runtime* type `Action`.

(Ignoring for now things like the `new` modifier on methods or explicit interface implementation.)